# make realtime timer using flipclock

Tags: javascript, socket.io, flipclock

I want to make realtime timer using flipclock. I have code for that but not working properly. In Timer when start button click timer will be started in all tabs of chrome(realtime) and when stop button click timer will be stopped in all tabs. In page refresh if timer already started then started and if stopped then stopped.

**Code:**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('//' + location.host + ':7878');
    // var autostart;
    var clock;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(localStorage.getItem("timer") ? localStorage.getItem("timer") : 0, {
            clockFaceOptions:  {
                autoStart: false
            },
            onStart: function() {
                // autostart = true;
                socket.emit('socket_timer', clock.getFaceValue());
            },
            onStop: function() {
                // autostart = false;
            },
            onInterval: function () {
                console.log(clock.getFaceValue());
                localStorage.setItem("timer", clock.getFaceValue());
                // socket.emit('socket_timer', clock.getFaceValue());
            }
        });
        socket.on('server_socket_timer',function(data) {
            clock.setFaceValue(data);
            clock.start();
        });
        socket.on('server_clock_stop', function () {
            clock.stop();
        });
        $('#start').click(function () {
            clock.start();               
        });
        $('#end').click(function () {
            clock.stop();
            socket.emit('clock_stop');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: To get help here, you need to describe both the expected behavior and the observed behavior and then explain exactly what is not working as you expect.  Since most people here won't know what FlipClock is, you should probably also describe what it is supposed to be doing for you.